# Storing colors in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm upgrading an old WinForms application to WPF and is wondering how to store a color in WPF?

In Winforms I had:

```
public System.Drawing.Color Color { get; set; }
```

But in WPF the Color-class doesn't exist. How do you achieve the same thing in WPF?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF, You can use **Color** like this:

```
public System.Windows.Media.Color Color { get; set; }
```

And in WPF, we can use `Brush` to control Background, Foreground and so on.Usually we use SolidBrush:

```
public System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
```

Comment: But yeah I would use Brush most likely rather than Color

Comment: Yes, In WPF, Brush is used more than color. I will update my answer.

Comment: It is worth noting that WPF also has a System.Windows.Media.Brushes class which provides predefined colours as brushes.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF you use Brush instead of Color. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.